# Angular service dependency injection

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

I need help with how I can inject a service into another service that I have. Here is the setting:

this is my main.ts where I bootstrapModule:

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(DTIframeModule, {
        preserveWhitespaces: false 
    }).then((ngModuleRef: NgModuleRef<DTIframeModule>) => {

        const rootInjector = ngModuleRef.injector;


        const instrumentationService = rootInjector.get(InstrumentationService);

        if (instrumentationService instanceof DTService) {
            const routeService = rootInjector.get(DTRouteService);
            instrumentationService.registerDTRouteService(routeService);
        }
    }
```

and this the detail of `InstrumentationService` and `DTService`:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class InstrumentationService {
    public abstract generateDTEvent(
        eventName: string,
        params?: Params): InstrumentationEvent;
}

@Injectable()
export class DTService implements InstrumentationService {
    private queuedEventsPopulatedWithRoute: boolean;
    // few other fields

    public registerRouteService(routeService: RouteService) {
       // some function
    }

    public generateDTEvent(
        eventName: string,
        params?: Params): InstrumentationEvent {
        // some service
        }
}
```

What I have issues with is that I would like to use a service called `WinService` inside `DTService`, I added the import:

```
import { WinService } from '../services/win.service';
```

and wanted to access it inside `DTService` like this:

`this.winService.native.events;`

But however I tried I am hitting the wall and getting error that this.winService is undefined. I tried adding a constructor to `DTService` and add `private readonly winService: WinService` and it is throwing injection error.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the `WinService` in the `providers` array of the module?

Comment: What does `WinService` look like? How does your constructor of  `DTService` look like when you import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `WinService` in to providers array of the module.

If it's provided in another module, please import that module to your module where you have provided `DTService`

Please read Angular Dependency Injection [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) for more information.

Comment: it is not directly included in the Module and it has been used in other part of the angular app, but when I try to add it DTService which is used inside BootstrapModule, it throws error. Do you recommend adding it to providers list in the main app module or instrumentationModule?

Comment: Both cases will work. But according to your business requirement you have to decide where you should provide it. If it's more related to instrumentationModule put it there. Else put it at app module.

Comment: put it on the main module, { provide: WinService },
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: DTPageErrorHandler }, and this.winService is used inside ErrorHandler and it throwing error that it is undefined. It wasn't throwing this error before and winService was working fine inside ErrorHandler

Comment: in place of   `{ provide: WinService }` try using `WinService`

Comment: If problem's still there please provide more code so I can review and give comments